# Is "very less" correct English?

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, expressions, adverbs, comparatives

Is using *very less* correct English? My friend suggests it should be *very little*. Are they both correct, or is there a difference?

Comment: You need to up the ante and say "very least" ... ^_^

Comment: ...at the very least?  ;-P

Comment: People in India use it all the time. There it is common to say "very less" when they mean "very little".

Comment: The idiomatic phrase *very less* is prevalent in neither AmE nor BrE, but is essentially a regionalism seen in the Indian subcontinent and probably in some other countries.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

"Very less" is incorrect. "Very little" or "much less" would be possible alternatives.

Some examples of how both phrases could be used:

> I paid very little for this jacket. I paid $500 for this jacket in
>   March; today I could buy it for much less.
>
> I have very little money. I have much less money today than I did on
>   Monday.

Comment: "I could not signal the chopper from my life raft because I had no flare gun. That's right, I was lost at sea **Very less**!" Very gun: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flare_gun

Comment: @Adarshnairy You are not supposed to leave an edit comment in the answer. You should leave it in **Edit Summary**.

Answer (score 8):

*Very less* isn't correct. It depends on exactly what you're trying to say though.

*Very little* implies a completely different meaning. If there is very little of something, it means a very small number. Whereas 'very less' (although wrong) implies that it is less than something else, or less than it was before.

> far less

or

> much fewer

is probably clearer.

Comment: Note that *far fewer* and *much less* also work. But people don't usually use *very* with *less* or *fewer*.

Answer (score 2):

Your friend is right -- "*very little*" is correct.  I've never seen "*very less*" used anywhere, and it feels awkward to me.

Comment: There are [many usages](http://www.google.com/search?q=very+less&hl=en&qscrl=1&prmd=ivnsfd&ei=FAZLTp2PKsPliALn4YmWBw&start=0&sa=N&biw=1188&bih=1481) of 'very less' in the web. But everything I checked points to a post from an Indian. :) So I guess it's an indian thing. Will try to avoid it in future.

Answer (score 0):

- Less is used with uncountable things quantity of water.
- Little is used with countable things like money.

Comment: Money is 99% of the time **un**countable, A: *How much money do you have?* B: *Very little*