# Can less be used without any comparison?

Tags: word-usage

Can I use "less" in sentences like this:

> 1 Why do we have so less number of students for this class?
>
> 2 My song collection is very less.

"Small" sounds better in both examples, but I would like to know if using "less" in these sentences is correct?

Comment: No. Incorrect syntax in both.
1) such a small number. 2) small

Comment: Not in these constructions, anyway. Both of these sentences are incorrect. _*So less_ is an ungrammatical compound; it should be _so little_; likewise, _*very less_ should be _very small_.

Comment: You possess a dictionary; why ask us whether its definition of *less* is correct?

Comment: With non-count nouns, _so much less_ may be used (there was so much less snow this March), but not _so less_ on its own.

Comment: It sets my StdAmEng native speaker's teeth on edge, but 'very less' is anecdotally the *preferred* way to say things like these examples in at least some variants of Indian English.  (India the country, just to be 100% clear.)  I'm told it's probably influence from Hindi.

Comment: Partly duplicate: http://english.stackexchange.com/q/38202/14666

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: Good example, but I think that's still a comparison. (It's not explicit, but the meaning there is, "There was so much less snow this March [than there was last March]."

Answer (score 2):

No, it isn't. *Less* is the comparative of *little*, and *least* is the superlative. You can no more say *My song collection is very less* than you can say *My song collection is very smaller*.

Comment: It isn't always the comparative of *little*. You can say "the peaches this year are *littler* than usual", but you can't say "the peaches this year are *less* than usual".

Comment: Yes. Though note that there can be an implied comparison. Like, in Romeo and Juliet, Juliet's mother tells her that she should marry the wealthy Paris, because, "So shall you share all that he doth possess, By having him, making yourself no less." No less than what? That what she has now. Etc.

Answer (score 1):

Less, more, fewer are comparative adjectives/adberbs.

Am I allowed to say

> I like eating durians because they are less pungent.
>
> Why is there so much less (for non-discretely countables) snow today?
>
> Why are there far fewer (for discretely countables) students today?

Yes, provided you have either an implied or prior situation for comparison.

Therefore,

> Miriam: I love eating petai peas.
>
> Aminah: I like eating durians because they are less pungent.

For the following two sentences, there are respective implied pre-existing situations available for comparison.

> Why is there so much less snow today? (implied comparison with yesterday or the last snow storm)
>
> Why are there far fewer students today? (implied comparison with yesterday or the last time the class was held)

Comment: This would be more convincing if you used the OP's sentences as examples.

Comment: @MrLister: But, as others have pointed out, the OP's examples are incorrect. (However, I could say "My music collection is much less eclectic than Barrie's," if that helps.)