# Possessive noun form of "country"

Tags: grammar, grammaticality

In a recent test, we were asked to identify the grammatically incorrect sentence from this:

> 1. They gave us the money back less the service charges of three hundred dollars.
> 2. This country's expenditure is not less than that of Bangladesh.
> 3. The committee initially asked for a funding of 2 million dollars, but later settled for a lesser sum.
> 4. This country's expenditure on educational reforms is very less.

The incorrect sentence *apparently* is the 4th one. But I don't see why.. All 4 sentences sound correct. The only thing one might have doubts about is the use of "country's" in place of "of this country". Is the correct form of the 4th sentence - The expenditure of this country on educational reforms is very less. ?

Comment: x *very less* -- is my guess, not *country's*.

Comment: The word *less* is a comparative; you can't use *very* in front of it. You can say *"Bruce is taller than Jim"* or *"Bruce is very tall".* You can't say *"Bruce is very taller".*

Comment: See this question: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/95958/can-less-be-used-without-any-comparison

Comment: @PeterShor But you can say *much taller* or *very much taller*.

Comment: *Country's* is as grammatical as *Mary's*. The only difference is that Mary is a proper noun. One need not say *the expenditures of Mary*. Certainly *very less* is wrong, as you have identified.

Comment: @bib: you can say *much less* and *very much less*, too. Both *less* and *taller* follow the rules for comparatives, which you can look up if you don't know them. (Unless you're suggesting that *very* is in front of *less* in *very much less*, but what I meant was directly in front.)

Comment: @PeterShor Thanks. I didn't think the problem could be there. My thoughts were fixated up on the possessive form of 'country'.

Comment: @PeterShor Obviously. But what are those rules? Both *very* and *much* can be adverbs suggesting *a lot*. But *very* cannot be used with comparatives. Their respective use seems idiomatic. Perhaps laying out the comparative rules for these idiomatic constructions should be an answer.

Comment: Based on the example given by @PeterShor , is it safe to conclude that 'very' can be applied to an adjective? "very tall" , "very rich", where 'very' implies more of that quality. But  not "very less" since "less" is not an adjective per se.. But "very little" is valid.

Comment: @sanjeev: comparatives and superlatives are types of adjectives, but types you can't use *very* with. You can apply *very* to any *gradable* adjective. You can't apply it to *ungradable* adjectives. Which adjectives are gradable? I don't know where you can get a good list; the lists I can find are written by prescriptive grammarians, who are often wrong about how people talk. Two truly ungradable adjective are *main* and *principal*. You can't say something is *very main*. But people say *very complete* all the time, despite the fact that it's on most of the lists of ungradable adjectives.

Comment: @PeterShor That's an answer, isn't it? Or very very close. It explains Barrie's answer in the linked question.

Comment: @bib: *Much* is an adverb in, for example, *much reduced circumstances*. I'd say that in *Bruce is much taller* it's a ***noun*** (eqv: *a great deal*), but I suppose you could say it's adverbial (eqv: *significantly*).

Comment: _Very_ (which I've never classed as an adverb) is idiosyncratic in its distribution. It is acceptable as an additional emphasiser of superlatives in expressions such as 'the very slightest sound', 'the very merest handful of tickets'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mistake is *very less*. The word *less* is a comparative adjective; you can't use *very* in front of comparatives. Most comparatives end with *-er*, and I'll use *taller* as an example. You can say:

> Bruce is taller than Jim.
>   Bruce is very tall.
>   Bruce is much taller than Jim.
>   Bruce is very much taller than Jim.

But not:

> *Bruce is very taller.
>   *Bruce is very taller than Jim.

You can use *very* in front of most adjectives. Which adjectives can't you use *very* in front of?  Comparatives and superlatives are one class of adjectives which don't take *very*. There is also a class of adjectives called *ungradable* which don't take *very*. Which adjectives are ungradable? This is a problem; I don't know where you can get a good list. The lists I can find are written by prescriptive grammarians, who are often wrong about how people really use language.

One truly ungradable adjective is *main* . You can't say something is *very main*. But people say *very complete* all the time, despite the fact that it's on many of the lists of ungradable adjectives.

Comment: The word _less_ is better analysed as a [comparative determiner](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/less) (the Collins analysis). In _we have a little dog_, 'little' is an adjective, ascribing an attribute to the referent of the noun (good old Fido, say). In _we have a little rice / we have little rice / we have less rice_, we are being given no information about the nature of the rice, but rather about the quantity. This ' [serving to express the reference of the noun or noun phrase in the context](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determiner) ' classes little / a little / less as determiners.

Comment: [Here](http://www.englishclub.com/grammar/adjectives-non-gradable.htm) is a great treatment of ungradeable adjectives, explaining why it wouldn't make sense to grade extreme (eg terrified), absolute (eg dead) and classifying (eg nuclear) adjectives.

Comment: @Edwin: that site gives "black" as non-gradeable, which is ridiculous. This is what I mean about these lists being written by prescriptive grammarians.

Comment: The primary sense 'of the very darkest color owing to the absence of or complete absorption of light; the opposite of white' is semantically ungradeable. The fact that we broaden, using 'blacker' to mean 'more nearly black' just as we use 'fuller' to mean 'more nearly full' is a complication. 'Black' is obviously an 'extreme' adjective, as is 'full'. I'd treat these (relatively few, I think) examples as exceptions to the rule. 'Deader' is sometimes used whimsically. 'Merest' really means 'mere' in bold print.

Comment: @Edwin: As the words are used, if *black* is ungradable, than all colors should be ungradable. [See Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=blacker%2Fblack%2Cvery+black%2Fblack%2Credder%2Fred%2Cvery+red%2Fred%2Cbluer%2Fblue%2Cvery+blue%2Fblue&year_start=1800&year_end=2009&corpus=15&smoothing=10&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2C%28blacker%20/%20black%29%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C%28very%20black%20/%20black%29%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C%28redder%20/%20red%29%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C%28very%20red%20/%20red%29%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C%28bluer%20/%20blue%29%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C%28very%20blue%20/%20blue%29%3B%2Cc0).

Comment: No; black and white have precise meanings, whereas red, purple, brown etc are terms covering ranges of hues / shades (and arguable ranges at that). It is often stated that scientifically, white and black are not colours. Again, 'off white' is, by the strict definition of white, not a type of white but an approximation to white.

Comment: @Edwin: People who actually speak English do not seem to make much of a distinction between *red* and *black* in terms of gradability, as evidenced by my Ngram above. The people who say *black* is ungradable and *red* is gradable seem to be arguing from a purely theoretical point of view (the definition of a prescriptive grammarian), since they are unsupported by actual usage. They are also not supported by [physics](http://phys.org/news/2011-09-darker-than-black-metamaterial-efficient-solar-cells.html).

Comment: There are few people who think that English is more unruly than I do. However, I feel that the semantic subdivisions of extreme and absolute (in this sense) adjectives, and the domain-specifying classifying adjectives, are worth keeping separate from the rest. Many of the examples in the first two classes accept sensible 'premodifiers' (though I'd prefer a different term) eg nearly dead; almost unique. Some common usages are rather loose (blacker; fuller). Using 'gradable / non-gradable' to describe the morphology in fashion is not, I feel, as valuable as examining what the adjectives do.